# Perl Error: Can't load GD.xs.dll for module GD

Tags: perl, gd, strawberry-perl

I've installed Strawberry Perl on my Windows Server 2019 machine and my Apache server keeps giving me the following errors when I try to run perl scripts:

`Can't load 'C:/usr/site/lib/auto/GD/GD.xs.dll' for module GD: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/usr/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.: D:/www/update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl, referer: http://update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl`

`: D:/www/update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl, referer: http://update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl`

`Compilation failed in require at C:/usr/site/lib/GD/Simple.pm line 160.: D:/www/update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl, referer: http://update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl`

`BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/usr/site/lib/GD/Simple.pm line 160.: D:/www/update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl, referer: http://update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl`

`Compilation failed in require at D:/www/update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl line 8.: D:/www/update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl, referer: http://update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl`

`BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at D:/www/update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl line 8.: D:/www/update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl, referer: http://update/cgi-bin/FILENAME.pl`

When I open the location C:\usr\site\lib\auto\GD\ the GD.xs.dll is sitting right there, so it's not missing.

These scripts worked before when I was using ActivePerl. I've tried to reinstall GD (in cpan: `force install GD`) and upgraded all modules (in cpan: `upgrade`) but that doesn't seem to do anything. Am I maybe missing some dependencies? Or is because I'm running a x64 machine and the dll file is incompatible with a 64bit system?

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated because this is starting to drive me mad.

Comment: What command are you running when you get those errors?

Comment: The error might not be referring to `GD.xs.dll` itself but to another library used by `GD.xs.dll`. Easiest solution might be to reinstall GD

Comment: @HåkonHægland I've updated my question. It's my Apache server that gives me these errors.

Comment: @ikegami Is there any way to find out if it's indeed another library and, if so, which one? Also, how would I reinstall GD? I already did a ```force install GD``` in cpan.

Comment: There are tools to inspect libraries, but I'm not familiar with them // That would reinstall, yes. If you still have the problem, then it more complicated then a library being removed/renamed since GD.xs.dll was created.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: apparently Windows needs to load the dll file on startup or something because after restarting my machine it seems to work...